# TfIdfVectorizer with grouped tokens

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I've vectorized ~1million of textual documents with TfIdfVectorizer.

```
vect1 = TfIdfVectorizer()
vect1.fit_transform(data)
```

Now I need to group some (semantically similar) tokens and repeat vectorization.

Replacing all tokens in the raw data with the new ones seems tedious and time consuming for me, since I intend to repeat the process for multiple grouping strategies.

I've tried

```
voc = vect1.vocabulary_
voc['cabman'] = voc['driver']
# grouping similar tokens to have the same ids ...
vect2 = TfIdfVectorizer(vocabulary=voc)
vect2.fit_transform(data)
```

> ValueError: Vocabulary contains repeated indices.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish it without touching the input data?

Comment: can you provide a small sample data set and desired data set?